# DevExpress dxSelectBox with Custom Store & Angular 6

Tags: angular, devexpress, devextreme

I am trying to setup a to use the DevExpress dxSelectBox while using a custom store. I have created a custom data source which is working correctly to load the list of items but not the **byKey**.

I have build a very simple example here with a fake data source but it is not showing the selected value

home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import DataSource from 'devextreme/data/data_source';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';
@Component({
   selector: 'home',
   templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  items = [
    { id: 123, name: 'John' },
    { id: 321, name: 'Bob' },
    { id: 42, name: 'Joe' },
    { id: 89, name: 'Suzy' },
    { id: 10, name: 'Jenny' },
  ];

  item = {
    person: { id: 123, name: 'John' }
  };

  editorOptions = {
    displayExpr: 'name',
    valueExpr: 'id',
    dataSource: null
  };

 constructor(
    private data: DataService
  ) {
    const vm = this;
    this.editorOptions.dataSource = new DataSource({
      load: function (loadOptions) {
        console.log('Loading');
        const promise1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          setTimeout(function () {
          console.log('resolving', vm.items);
           resolve(
             {
               data: vm.items
             }
           );
          }, 3000);
        });

        return promise1;


      }
      byKey: function (key) {

       console.log('Getting Person', key);
        const promise1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
         setTimeout(function () {
           console.log('Getting Person', key);
           resolve({ id: 123, name: 'John' });
         }, 3000);
        });

       return promise1;
     }
   });

 }

 ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

The HTML for this component is fairly simple:

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="item">
  <dx-form id="form" [(formData)]="item">
    <dxi-item dataField="person" editorType="dxSelectBox" 
[editorOptions]="editorOptions"></dxi-item>
  </dx-form>
</div>
```

Why is this not showing the selected value?

I have added a plunker example https://plnkr.co/edit/5VtwIBw6ZMasEmkcxfax?p=options

Comment: Shouldn't it be `id` and not the whole object since you're using `valueExpr="id"`? Please refer to https://plnkr.co/edit/kbzom7ZWVgW41Fyj1Ky0?p=preview

Comment: What I started out trying was not using the valueExpr since I want it to select the whole object and not on ID, is that possible?

Comment: Of course, just use existing object e.g through `this.items[0]` See also https://plnkr.co/edit/goYBmXc4YSszpm75n9hy?p=preview

Comment: But I have a custom data source where it is loading the values async. That is what my demo is trying to show, it is not working when there is a custom data source. It calls the `byKey` function which calls the resolve but the UI is not updating appropriately